# Launching a specific Activity from an Alarm - even when application is closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager

I'm looking to use `AlarmManager` to launch a specific activity (ie. not my main one) and cannot seem to figure out how to do it.

I can launch the main activity (the one that opens when the application is launched normally) using the code found in another answer, but I want to launch a specific activity within my application.

Is there a way to do this? All the answers I've seen only relate to opening the application to its main activity.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: If this isn't possible, is there a way I can tell the MainActivity I am opening to execute a specific section of code that can replicate my Alarm Activity that I was hoping to jump to? 
IE. if this is a limitation, maybe open the main activity and then run code to open the alarm activity if the main activity "knows" it was opened by the alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, the basic solution given here 
[AlarmManager, BroadcastReceivers, Activities](https://blog.alexwendland.com/2013/alarmmanager-broadcastreceivers-activities/)

Comment: What you are looking for is possible just set the alarm where you want and then use Intent to launch the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just build a regular `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityToLaunch.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Replace `ActivityToLaunch.class` with the class name of the `Activity` that should be launched.